# Search Nearby School at current location using Google maps?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, currentlocation

I am trying to show nearby schools at current location but, i dont know how to merge both of them, I made a separate program for getting current location, but now i want to show nearby locations around this current location. I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iem_usman/hwqurLrh/). Here we are giving static lat and longs i want them to be my current locations lat and longs. So that on my current location i can see nearby schools

```
var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

And here you need to remove callback from the script tag **callback=initMap** so it will look like as below.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places" async defer></script>
```

Because first we are calling getLocation() and after getting value from geolocation we are calling `initMap();` manually.

```
var temp_lat = '';
    var temp_lng = '';
    var map;
    var infowindow;
    getLocation();
    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
            temp_lat = 0.0; //set default lat value
            temp_lng = 0.0; //set default lng value
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    temp_lat = position.coords.latitude;
    temp_lng = position.coords.longitude;
    initMap();
}


 function initMap() 
 {
 var pyrmont = {lat: temp_lat, lng: temp_lng};
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
 { center: pyrmont, zoom: 15 }); 
 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
 var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);  service.nearbySearch(
 { location: pyrmont, radius: 500, type: ['school'] },
 callback); } 
 function callback(results, status) { 
 if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) 
 { 
 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
 { createMarker(results[i]); } } } function createMarker(place) { var placeLoc = place.geometry.location; var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: place.geometry.location }); google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { infowindow.setContent(place.name); infowindow.open(map, this); }); }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: using this code. navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); So you just need to create showPosition function() with position argument this is default functionality by google map.

Comment: yar are fast :p

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp
Use html5 geolocation to get current location it will return lat long and then afterwards pass it to pyrmont variable lat and long